# How to call external javascript function in html with onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two javascript function in my index.js file saved in the same folder directory as my html file but for some reasons i am able to call only one of the function the second function is not getting called.

index.js

```
function cond(){
    alert('Is the form correct');
}

function isNumber(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(charCode));
}
```

index.html

```
<?php require "header.html"?>

<label>Year</label>
<input type ="number" min="1950" max="2050" name="year" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>

<label>school</label>
<input type ="text" onclick="cond();" name="school" required>
```

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <main>
```

Am able to use the isNumber() function successfully but the other function cond() is not getting called when the text is clicked

Comment: Not related to your question, but you are including partial header for every page.
It might be better to define layout.html with included content instead with `require`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `cond` is shadowed by other function? Try changing it's name. Or take a look at the console output.

Usually it is a good practice to retrieve element and then bind event
listener to it. Now your HTML is coupled with the JS. Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/nr65sLc0/

```
var schoolInput = document.getElementById('school-input');
if (schoolInput) {
  schoolInput.addEventListener('click', cond);
}
```

Remember to add id attribute for each input.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file, you can't use PHP ( you required a file ) because index.html extension is `HTML` at first you should change that to `PHP` then both of them will work correctly.

Change `index.html` to `index.php`

Comment: sorry that was a mistake in the question the file name is actually index.php but it still not working even with that

Comment: So Do you have another file that you've included it in you file? because both functions are working for me. Please take a look at your console. Is there any error?

Comment: **Uncaught ReferenceError: cond is not defined** this the error from the console

Comment: I didn't get such an error, maybe you have a problem adding files. Why don't you put your codes ( header.html & index.php ) in a PHP file? and another thing is that the `<main>` tag in header.html doesn't have closed tag.

Comment: i have the closing tag for the `<main>` in another html file still the same issue but never mind i guess i just have to used the script  in the index file directly I was only trying to clean up the code a bit.Thanks anyways